# Rust debugging - not hitting any breakpoints in visual studio code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, rust, lldb

I am trying to look at some breakpoints in code. I installed `rust-analyzer`, `codelldb`, and `native debug` plugins for code and generated the default `launch.json`. It seems like the debugger is not attaching properly to the process and runs right through the breakpoints. It's probably something simple that's going wrong - here's my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests in library 'thedrewreport'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--lib",
                    "--package=thedrewreport"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "thedrewreport",
                    "kind": "lib"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'thedrewreport'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=thedrewreport",
                    "--package=thedrewreport"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "thedrewreport",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'thedrewreport'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--bin=thedrewreport",
                    "--package=thedrewreport"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "thedrewreport",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHbWM.jpg) of the debugger in action and a [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeqVp.jpg) of the plugins installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you building without optimizations and with debug info?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Eventually I noticed that someone had added `debug = false` to the dev profile in our workspace `Cargo.toml`. This broke the debugger because it prevents debug symbols from being included in the binary.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHall such a simple fix but can be a pain when you are new to Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the target floder, than press F5 to auto build and debug.
It's maybe because you build from console, but build without debug info.